# Extracting text without tags of HTML with Beautifulsoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to extract this part of text but i don't figure it out how to do it, i'm working with several html files locally.

```html
<HTML><HEAD><STYLE>SOME STYLE CODE</STYLE></HEAD><META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<BODY>
<H1>SOME TEXT I DONT WANT</H1>
THIS TEXT IS WHICH I WANT
<H1>ANOTHER TEXT I DONT WANT</H1>
ANOTHER TEXT THAT I WANT
[.. Continues ..]
</BODY></HTML>
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT: I have tried with this code but sometimes prints the h1 tags

```
import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for file in glob.glob('Logs/Key*.html'):
    with open(file) as f:
        htmlfile = f.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile, 'html.parser')
        c = soup.find('body').findAll()
        for i in c:
            print i.nextSibling
```

EDIT 2: Actually the problem is that the html file has only one line, so when i try to run that code with this html, also prints the h1 tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmlfile = '<HTML><HEAD><STYLE>SOME STYLE CODE</STYLE></HEAD><META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><BODY><H1>SHIT</H1>WANTED<H1>SHIT</H1><H1>SHIT</H1>WANTED<H1>SHIT</H1>WANTED<H1>SHIT</H1>WANTED</BODY><HTML>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile, 'html.parser')
c = soup.find('body').findAll()
for i in c:
    print i.nextSibling
```

Prints:

```
WANTED
<h1>SHIT</h1>
WANTED
WANTED
WANTED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you can put HTML_TEXT as the html you got from scrapping the url.

```
y = BeautifulSoup(HTML_TEXT)

c = y.find('body').findAll(text=True, recursive=False)

for i in c:
    print i
```

Comment: This works, but also prints the text that i dont want, the <h1> tags :S

Comment: can you send the url that you're extracting from, because with this example it's working fine in my PC.

Comment: I just edit the question, the problem is when the html file has only one line

Comment: now I got what you want, check the above edited answer this will work for you.