# Get content between tags using beatifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'am trying to get all content between `<h2>` and `</h2>`. Like this one:

```
<h2> Header 1 </h2>
This is an example text for <a href="https://example.com">site</a>
Any HTML-Code can appear 
<br />
<p>
<h2> Header 2 </h2>
Some other text with no tags
<h2> Header 3 </h2>
```

Result should be:

```
This is an example text for <a href="https://example.com">site</a>
Any HTML-Code can appear 
<br>
<p>
```

And:

```
Some other text with no tags
```

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you get the whole text and then use decompose() to remove the h2-tags?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Given what you state below, your question is kind of unclear. I don't understand if whther you are looking for the text only which is between two tags or if you want to keep the `<a>` and `<br>` tags as well along with the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip, but that is not exaclty what I require.
May I told you to less Information.

There is a lot of content before and after this text and I only want to grep the text between `</h2>` and `<h2>`

If i use decompose() it only deletes h2-Tags, but all other stuff are still there.
My problem is similar to that one: [Extracting text without tags of HTML with Beautifulsoup Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859271/extracting-text-without-tags-of-html-with-beautifulsoup-python)

I found a possible Solution:

```
content = soup.find_all("div",class_="class")
begin = str(content).find("Header 1</h2>")
end = str(content).find("<h2>Header 2")
print(str(content)[begin:end])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for decompose.

```
while soup.find("h2") != None: # the find method returns the found element
    soup.h2.decompose() 

>>> \nThis is an example text for <a href="https://example.com">site</a>\nAny HTML-Code can appear \n<br>\n<p>\n\nSome other text with no tags\n</p></br>
```

Or more subtly:

```
soup.h2.decompose()
second_text = soup.h2.next_sibling
while soup.find("h2") != None:
    soup.h2.decompose()

print soup, second_text


>>> This is an example text for <a href="https://example.com">site</a>
    Any HTML-Code can appear 
    <br>
    <p>

    Some other text with no tags
    </p></br> 
    Some other text with no tags
```